# add uilabel when no data is shown

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, uilabel, tableview

I want to be able to set up instructions via a uilabel of how to add data when no data is shown (nsmutablearray). How do I do that. And furthermore, how do I make it disappear when data comes up?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple check should do it

```
if ([self.myArray count] == 0) {
    self.myLabel.hidden = NO;
} else {
    self.myLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the UILabel to your UIViewController subclass with an outlet, then send messages to that object to set it's text property when interesting stuff happens.

Without more specifics, it's hard to help any more than that.